# Superposition of momentum plane waves for a WF: discrete of continuous?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum, fourier-transform, superposition

On the one hand there is a theorem that states that *any reasonable* wave function $\Psi$ can be written as a superposition of eigenstates of $\hat Q$ (a hermitian operator).

So if $\Psi _i$ are the eigenstates, we have: $$\Psi (x) = \Sigma \alpha _i \Psi _i$$

And for the momentum operator $\hat p = \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ we have:
$$\Psi (x) = \Sigma \alpha _i e^{ixp/ \hbar}$$

On the other hand we have the Fourier transform of $\Psi$ whose result is: $$\Psi (x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \int dp \Phi(p)e^{ipx /\hbar}$$

I am really confused about these two formulas: how can we have $\Psi$ as a countable sum of the exponentials (first formula) and at the same time as an uncountable sum of the exponentials (second formula) ?

I know very few things in maths, but apparently the sum of the first formula is $\aleph _0$ and the second one is $\aleph _1$ ... How can this be?...

PS: it's been no more than one month ago since I started QM, sorry if the question is very basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your text didn't say clear enough,
what the $x$ domains are for these two different situations.

- The discrete sum
  $$\Psi(x)=\sum_n\alpha_n e^{ixp_n/\hbar}$$
  is the decomposition when the $x$ domain is *finite*,
  e.g. $x\in [0,L]$.
  In this case only discrete values are allowed for $p_n$:
  $$p_n=\hbar\frac{2\pi n}{L}\quad \text{with }n\in\{...,-2,-1,0,1,2, ...\}$$
- The continuous integral
  $$\Psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \int dp\ \Phi(p)e^{ipx /\hbar}$$
  is the decomposition when the $x$ domain is *infinite*,
  i.e. $x\in (-\infty,\infty)$.
  In this case all real values for $p$ are allowed.

Comment: Ahh ok that's what *reasonable wavefunction* means

Comment: So *reasonable* means that the WF has a finite domain ?

Comment: @niobium *Reasonable* usually means normalizable, and satisfying the given boundary conditions (if there is a boundary).

Comment: OK. Also: can the free particle WF be decomposed as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of the momentum operator? I feel like it's impossible

Comment: @niobium Yes, a free particle $\Psi(x)$ can be decomposed as a continuous
combination of eigenvectors of the $\hat{p}$ operator. This is essentially the
Fourier transformation.